# Empty Button error for ASTRA CART DRAWER after WAVE report scanning

Tags: html, css, accessibility

Running the Wave Report tool, I got an error about `<button type="button" class="astra-cart-drawer-close">` saying

> A button is empty or has no value text

The site is WP, built with ASTRA Theme and Elementor. Is there a CSS code solution or any other?

The site is [www.defkalionsa.gr](http://www.defkalionsa.gr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what's causing the problem but I can't select the right things on the page to get the X-close button to appear.

```html
<div id="astra-mobile-cart-drawer" class="astra-cart-drawer open-right">
  <div class="astra-cart-drawer-header">
    <button type="button" class="astra-cart-drawer-close">
      <span class="ahfb-svg-iconset ast-inline-flex svg-baseline">
        <svg class="ast-mobile-svg ast-close-svg"...>
          <path d="M5.293..."></path>
        </svg>
      </span> 
    </button>
    <div class="astra-cart-drawer-title">Shopping Cart</div>
  </div>
  <div class="astra-cart-drawer-content"></div>
</div>
```

You have a `<button>` with an embedded `<svg>` and I presume the `<svg>` is just a big 'X' to represent a close button but there's nothing to tell assistive technology such as a screen reader what the `<svg>` represents.  You can fix this by adding `aria-label="close"` to the `<button>`.

```html
    <button aria-label="close" type="button" class="astra-cart-drawer-close">
```

(For Internet Explorer, if you care, you also need `<svg focusable="false">` so that the keyboard user can't tab to the `<svg>`).

The `class` on the containing `<div>` says `astra-mobile-cart-drawer` so I presume this button is only shown in mobile view.  I switched to mobile view in the browser but still couldn't get this button to appear.  I added something to the cart and displayed the cart but still no luck.

You can still fix the problem with `aria-label` but I was really hoping to see the X-close button in action to confirm what it's trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much @slugocious for the answer, it seems the issue has been fixed with an update of the Astra theme. Have not tried your solution